# Using VST.net with Unity3d to create a simple VST host

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, vst

I've successfully simplified the [Vst.net host sample](https://github.com/obiwanjacobi/vst.net/tree/master/Source/Samples/Jacobi.Vst.Samples.Host) to directly load a vst instrument. Mostly I've just stripped out the GUI and made it automatically fire a few test notes. This code works when I build it as a console application.

```
using System;
using Jacobi.Vst.Core;
using Jacobi.Vst.Interop.Host; 
using NAudio.Wave;
using CommonUtils.VSTPlugin;

namespace Jacobi.Vst.Samples.Host
{
///<Summary>
/// Gets the answer
///</Summary>
public class pianoVST
{
    ///<Summary>
    /// Gets the answer
    ///</Summary>
    public static VST vst = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Play some test notes.
    /// </summary>
    public void playTest()
    {
        var asioDriverNames = AsioOut.GetDriverNames();
        if (asioDriverNames.Length > 0)
        {
            MidiVstTest.UtilityAudio.OpenAudio(MidiVstTest.AudioLibrary.NAudio, asioDriverNames[0]);
            MidiVstTest.UtilityAudio.StartAudio();
            vst = MidiVstTest.UtilityAudio.LoadVST("[path-to-vst-dll]");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                vst.MIDI_NoteOn(60, 100);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                vst.MIDI_NoteOn(60, 0);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

However, when I build this as a dll, import it into Unity and then attach it to a simple GameObject, I'm not able to get it to run or build. The error message I get is:

```
ArgumentException: The Assembly Jacobi.Vst.Interop is referenced by Jacobi.Vst.Samples.Host ('Assets/Jacobi.Vst.Samples.Host.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
```

I've rebuilt the C++ interop dll from source but nothing I do makes it work with Unity.

Is there something I can do to make the Jacobi.Vst.Interop dll work nicely with Unity?

Comment: I do not know anything about Unity, but perhaps the fact that the Interop dll is mixed code (.NET + C++) is detected and not allowed in unity...? (assuming you have it deployed)

Answer (score 0):

VST.Net has a dependency on the VC110.CRT package. That error could be a result of not have the VC runtime installed.

https://github.com/obiwanjacobi/vst.net/blob/master/docs/Using_VST.NET.md