# How to send MIDI from Unity to external VST

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, midi, vst

Following on from [my failed attempt to run a VST instrument from inside Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437265/using-vst-net-with-unity3d-to-create-a-simple-vst-host), my new approach is to send midi messages from Unity to an external host.

To achieve this I've been trying to follow [this approach](https://forum.image-line.com/viewtopic.php?t=155550):

1. Install loopMIDI (http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/loopmidi.html)
2. Create a virtual MIDI port within loopMIDI
3. Download the Sanford C# MIDI Toolkit http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6228/C-MIDI-Toolkit
4. Add a Reference to the MIDI Toolkit in your project
5. Write some code i.e.:

   ```
   private OutputDevice outDevice = null;

   private void MIDITest()
   {
       int devices = OutputDevice.DeviceCount;

       if (devices == 0)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("No MIDI output devices available.", "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
           return;
       }

       if (outDevice != null)
       {
           outDevice.Close();
       }

       outDevice = new OutputDevice(0);    // Change this for other MIDI devices
       outDevice.Error += inDevice_Error;
       outDevice.Reset();

       // Send a Note On
       ChannelMessage cm = new ChannelMessage(ChannelCommand.NoteOn, 0, 60, 127);
       outDevice.Send(cm);
   }
   ```

I've managed to do all of these steps, however, I'm still not able to detect any midi messages coming out from Unity. I've tried installing [Midi Ox](http://www.midiox.com/) to monitor the midi signals but it doesn't seem to be showing my virtual midi port and there seems to be no midi activity, despite all of my Unity code running fine. The Unity game is actually playing the midi file I have loaded, so I know my Unity code is running correctly, I just can't seem to get the virtual midi port configured correctly.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: First thing to do is create non Unity project and see if that piece of code works. If it works, show us how you installed the SDK in Unity. Screenshots are even better

Comment: @Programmer - I've just put together a small c# console app which returns OutputDevice.DeviceCount as 1 with loopMIDI running, indicating that it's not working correctly. It seems that no matter how many virtual midi ports I create, none are working as expected. At the moment I don't think that loopMidi is doing its job...

Comment: Well, there you go. don't waste your time with it in Unity if it can't even work in a non Unity environment. I suggest you comment on the project' codeproject page. Maybe the author can help you

Comment: You could also try using MIDI.NET https://github.com/obiwanjacobi/midi.net (Windows only)